# my Form is passing a NoneType value to my model method calculation, Am I missing instancing something?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass the input of a Form to my model method, to make some calculation based on my model field database values.

I know I can do it with custom tag filters, but that's not effcient as I need to do complex calculation later.
I've read somewhere that in Django you cannot pass paramaters to Models, but that sounds to stupid to be true...

Am I missing instancing something somewhere ??

The error when I save the new value in the form is :

np = self.price * value
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int''

so it is related

It's also very confusing because if I set a default value inside my method, the calculation is rendering fine in the template.

I would really appreciate some help

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku

    def multi(self, value = 2):  #THIS DEFAULT '2' IS PROCESSED BY THE METHOD
        np = self.price * value  #AND RENDERS A NP VALUE IN THE TEMPLATE
        return np
```

View

```
from .models import Product
from .forms import Input

def index(request):
    list = Product.objects.all()
    value = 0   #just to check

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Input(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            value = request.POST.get('data')
            value = form.cleaned_data.get('data')

            p = Product()   # IS THIS EVEN THE CORRECT SPOT THE CODE ???
            p.multi(value)   


    else:
        form = Input(request.POST or None)


    return render(request , 'multi/index.html', {'form' : form, 'list' : list, 'value' : value } )
```

template

```
{{ value }}

 {% for item in list %}  

        {{ item.sku }}  {{ item.price }} {{item.multi}} 

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not assign a value to your new Product instance price attribute. So it's default value is `None`. You should probably set the price when creating your product. Like this by exemple : `p = Product(price=42)`

Comment: Merci pour l'info. but that doesnt work either.
 If I edit the code like you suggested, upon saving the form nothing happens, but the code doesn't crash either